# Background Subtaction using Emgu cv

Tags: c#, background, emgucv, background-subtraction

I need to know that is there **a method to remove the background of a live streaming web cam.**  There is a method called **background Subtractor**. If anyone knows to use that please help me out with the issue..

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question). Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an image of the background you can just calculate

I - B

Where I is the Image and B is the background (of type say,  Image)

B - I

Will also work.

Since images don't store negative numbers, you may wish to combine these both using

(I - B) + (B - I)

And convert the result to grayscale.

I method which I have found works better is to do this using fourier transforms.

ie:

F^-1(F(I) - F(B))

for example

```
    CvInvoke.cvDFT(video.Convert<Gray, Single>().Ptr, DFT.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_FORWARD, -1);
    CvInvoke.cvDFT(Background.Convert<Gray, Single>().Ptr, DFTBack.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_FORWARD, -1);

    CvInvoke.cvDFT((DFTBack - DFT).Convert<Gray, Single>().Ptr, originalLeft.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_INVERSE, -1);
    CvInvoke.cvDFT((DFT - DFTBack).Ptr, originalRight.Ptr, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_INVERSE, -1);
```

This works well when the foreground is partially translucent.

There's also the built in [Foreground detector](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.2.1/document/html/e0b3b3f7-2a3a-18a0-8ff4-65b9f0a5da5e.htm)